# Flutter - Inverse of NumberFormat.compactCurrency()

Tags: flutter

How can I extract the real number from an already converted number by the method .

**The method :**

```
NumberFormat.compactCurrency(decimalDigits: 1, symbol: '').format(number)
```

Example :
1.2K ==> 1200

Comment: You should retain the original number and only use the formatted number for display purposes. Then the problem goes away.

Comment: The right way, Thanks 